# How to run update query after all concurrent pending queries have executed in JDBC or MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, concurrency

I am designing a system in which when a request comes to web server, the request data is inserted in DB and auto-increment id is generated.

Now there are some  x number of task to be completed for each request, where each task roughly takes 0-20 sec.

Using the auto generated  id as reference, the web server publishes message to a message broker(RabbitMQ) for each task to be completed by workers **running concurrently**. When any task is complete its status is updated in DB by inserting a row.

I want to update the table (like set status of overall request) when all tasks are complete. How should I proceed in my scenario ? Is there a way to run a query when all pending tasks are complete ?

I have tried checking after each task completion that if all other task are complete or not. If all other are complete then I updated the table else did nothing. But this fail if there are 2 task remaining to be completed and both get completed and check at the same time. Both will see that 1 task is still pending and no one will update the table.

I am using JDBC with MYSQL database at web server.

Please help.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you can get in trouble if two things (can) happen at the same time, you have a race condition, and in a database, the way around this is a transaction. A transaction can prevent both workers to check/update the status at the same time. Without seeing your code/tables, we cannot tell you how to do that exactly, but you may try to  e.g. first select all other rows for that id (with `for update`), have a counter or a status field "I am currently checking for completion" (which, due to transactions, only one worker can set)

Comment: Another way that solves this in MQ-logic instead of database logic: let the task-creator add another task to your queue (or probably a different queue), which just checks if if all other tasks are done and if not, either idles until they are or requeues the task. A similar way would be to use something like [Distributed Semaphores with RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/02/19/distributed-semaphores-with-rabbitmq/). Both solve the race condition issue on the MQ-level instead of the database level, which you may prefer.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for your solution. I solved the problem using a modified version of your answer. I added a counter field in the status row which increment whenever a task gets completed. Instead of selecting all rows for that id with FOR UPDATE, I just performed a SELECT ..FOR UPDATE (row lock) query in a transaction on the row in which status need to updated only when the counter is 1 less than the total count. In the way task table can be updated simultaneously.